# How do I run a simple each-do loop that combines columns from different tables? (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to loop through two separate columns' worth of data, using an each-do loop. I want questions to show up on the page, followed by user's email and update_last. I am a newbie and am not sure how to draw from separate columns in separate databases at the same time. Here is my code:

> ```
> <ul>
> <% @questions.each do |question| %>
> <hr>
>     <li><%= **question**.title %></li>
>     <li><%= **question**.user_id %></li>
>     <li><%= **users**.email %></li>
> <% end %>
> </ul>
> ```

Any help would be awesome. I am just starting to learn RoR and there's so much info!!

Thanks in advance.

-T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup your models:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
end

# app/models/question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Add `user_id` column to your `questions` table:

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToQuestions user_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Then, in your corresponding controller action:

```
def your_action_method
  @user = User.find(1) # find a user
end
```

Then, in your corresponding view:

```
<ul>
  <% @user.questions.each do |question| %>
      <li><%= question.title %></li>
      <li><%= question.user_id %></li>
      <li><%= @user.email %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This is a basic working setup so that you can kick start. But, there are more to do. Definitely check out the [official Rails Guide for Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Also, while creating owned objects (`question`), you have to associate that to the proper owner object (`user`) so that you can do: `user.questions` at any point of time to get the `questions` of that particular `user`. Something like this:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@question = Question.create(title: 'Title', body: 'body', user_id: @user.id)
```

You can also add [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) in your `Question` model to ensure that the `user_id` is present while creating a `question` record:

```
# app/models/question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: KM Rakibul Islam, I tried to message you to personally thank you but there doesn't seem to be an option for me to do this. In any case, I just wanted to say that i really appreciate you having taken the time out of your day to clarify this issue for me. It has been a real pain point and I appreciate you alleviating this stress for me. Many many thanks!

Comment: @Toddsqui You are most welcome. Glad to know that I could help. If it solved your problem, you can accept the answer. To see how that works, see this post please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done. You have definitely provided the best answer. Thank you so much. I appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Learn active record association. Setup user has many questions in your model.
Then when you iterate through your users collection object as user as single object inside the each block, you will have a methods question (e.g. user.questions). Now iterate through user.questions you will receive question for that specific user. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html